# Azure enterprise admin consent to dynamic app scopes

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

Is it possible to enable admin consent for dynamic application type scopes(not delegated, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/permissions-consent-overview))?

I have an azure application that's using multiple scopes, for purposes of this conversation lets limit them to:

Mail.Read, Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.Send

I want to enable **enterprise admins** to dynamically consent to any combination of Read and Write permissions for all users in their enterprise. For example, one admin wants to grant us only Mail.ReadBasic, while somebody else wants to grant us Mail.Read + Mail.Send.

Important to note that these need to be app type scope, **not delegated**, because we need to use retrieved token for some background processes before they enter the app. Needles to say, `./default` does not work for me in this case because it requests admin to consent to all permissions that are defined in the app.

Looking at the docs, [some pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin) says that this may be possible ("Instead you can use dynamic consent to add the permissions you want to be in the consent screen at run time, rather than using /.default."), while [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#token-request) say I need to use `/.default`.

So far I've tried:

- Client credentials flow

  - Allows only `./default` as scope, but **token retrieved this way can be used for all users in the enterprise**
  - Seems to make no difference whether I use `common` or `{tenant_id}` in adminconsent API
- authorization_code flow

  - This is the one that's used for single users in our app
  - In this flow, admin gets asked to accept only permissions that I've specified but the token that's retrieved this way works a bit odd:

    - I can read all user's profile using that token(using User.Read.All scope, used it as test only)
    - Other scopes(such as Mail.Read and Mail.Send) work only for admin, **even though consent screen had `Consent on behalf of your organisation` checked**
  - Also, this seems to allow only `delegated` permission type(Checked in `Enterprise applications` part in azure admin panel)
- App roles

  - Ive had the idea of creating roles within the app and assign each role to a set of scopes, but I haven't had much success with this, not sure if this is intended way of using them.

How things are looking right now, we will need to have 4 apps with following permissions:

1. Mail.Read
2. Mail.ReadBasic
3. Mail.Read + Mail.Send
4. Mail.ReadBasic + Mail.Send

I'm finding documentation somewhat confusing on this, and I think I'm either misinterpreting some part of it or that I'm missing some crucial part of the puzzle.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Azure AD Application and added API permissions:

[image]

To **enable admin consent for dynamic application type scopes**, I tried the below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/v2.0/adminconsent ?client_id=ClientID&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read &redirect_uri=RedirectUrl&state=12345
```

A prompt screen generated to grant Admin Consent to **`Mail.Read`** only app permission:

[image]

But it got added as an **Delegated permission** like below:

[image]

> **Note that:**
>
> - Currently Application permissions doesn't support Dynamic Consent and it adds the permissions as Delegated.
> - It is not possible to consent Existing Application permissions individually and even new application permissions cannot be passed dynamically in the scope parameter in the admin consent or any authentication endpoint.
> - Delegated permissions support Dynamic Consent and application permission only have static scope assignments.
> - All the application permissions added to the Azure AD application should be consented by the Global Admin.

To grant **Admin Consent to all the Application permissions**, you can make use of below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/v2.0/adminconsent ?client_id=ClientID&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default &redirect_uri=RedirectUrl &state=12345
```

[image]

To achieve the scenario where Admin wants to grant single/combination of Application API permissions, you need to create different Azure AD applications for the permissions.